# Joining 2 tables SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I m trying to fetch data from 2 table aisle and type.  The `aisle` table has following construct:

```
aisle_id | name | x | y
```

and the `type` table has following construct

```
type_id | name | aisle_id (FK)
```

`aisle_id` is the foreign key.

I'm using this sql query which works but, not as expected:

```
SELECT NAME,X, Y FROM type, aisle where Name ="bread"
```

What this statement returns me is, it returns bread but also returns all the data from the X and Y, which i do not want, I just want the x and y related to bread. So could anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Hint:  both tables have an `aisle_id` and a `JOIN` should have an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try joining the two on aisle_id as below:

```
SELECT t.Name, a.X, a.Y
FROM aisle a INNER JOIN type t 
ON   a.aisle_id = t.aisle_id
WHERE a.Name ="bread"
```

Answer (score 0):

With a simple Google search, and since you know what you need (join), the first result came directly from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

> Some join examples:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2;

SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id;

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 USING (id);

SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.id=table3.id;
```

In your case it would be:

```
SELECT aisle.NAME, aisle.X, aisle.Y FROM type JOIN aisle ON type.type_id = aisle.type_id WHERE aisle.Name ="bread"
```